# When change Windows default Icons functions get deactivated

Tags: windows-10, icons, disk-image, dll, default-settings

Hey I have changed some icons in the Imageres.dll.mun file. Now some functions are gone can someone explain me why? DO the default Icons contain code? Here one [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9Hkq.png).
Here is no bar anymore that shows how much diskspace is used
or another example: the default folder icons do not autorefresh anymore.

I hope you guys can answer me why it is so  :D
Best Regards,
Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think they contain code, but rather they contain several context-specific alternate icons. For example, this is the windows folder icon (obviously):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/47jub.png

But in this screenshot, you can see the same icon but with text files in one folder and a document and subfolder in another:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/enBwM.png

Those aren't icons of the 'real' documents that are inside those folders. As far as I know, they're just alternate versions of the folder icon that are packed together with the folder icon. Windows looks to see what's in the folder and selects the most appropriate icon from the pack to use.

If I change the icon of those folders though, this behaviour will no longer happen - they'll always have the icon I chose - no matter what files or folders are inside

So your HDD icon probably comes with several variants inside it (eg. one for empty, one for 25% full, one for 50% full etc.). But when you change the icon, you replace just the base icon, so all of those other variations are lost (until you reset the icon to default)

There's no way that I know of to solve this issue. :( There's a workaround you can do that partly masks the problem, but doesn't solve it. I did this myself recently.

I changed one of my folder icons to be more prominent, so that I would spot it easier among many other folders. See the "steamapps" folder here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTHeJ.png

I used a similar style to the default Windows style, but a little larger, with more contrast and more definition. But so that it wouldn't just look like an empty folder (which would *decrease* its prominence), I purposely added a subfolder and document into that icon. If were to delete everything inside it, its icon will still show up with that subfolder and document. But since my *steamapps* folder is never empty, it works out just fine, and it looks appropriate.

If you wanted to, you could do something similar, and edit your icon in a graphics program. For example if your hard drive is always about three-quarters full, you could add in a 75% bar to the icon. It's certainly not a perfect solution, and you might get a rude shock one day when the HDD turns out to be 99% full. But at least it won't look so strangely 'empty' as it does now.

Comment: Thank you for this long answer :) but do you know what I mean ? ups sry postet to soon wait i add more text ^^

Comment: I did not just change the icons i did change the default Windows Icons the the dll file and it does show me what is in my folder: https://imgur.com/j8csXyY here is the Problem it does not autorefresh anymore after changes has been done it must be done by myself with f5 and for the Disk Driver icon there is only the Disk Icon without any Bar: https://imgur.com/F46kGyC  Well I did already a lot of Icons :P but the Driver Icons just dont want to https://imgur.com/iLgS7nw also a very bad Idea is to change the Icon of explorer.exe after that your PC is broken :D

Comment: I've also noticed that windows takes a long time to refresh icons, and seems to do so sporadically. I think it's probably normal, but you don't tend to notice it until you do your own icons.

In case something has gone wrong, you can force a refresh of the icon cache by deleting this file: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\iconCache.db

Comment: Regarding your bar on your hard drive icon, are you referring to this one that is shown alongside the icon?

https://i.imgur.com/64gGZiN.png

Because that's the only one that I have (I don't have a bar ON the icon itself), and I've never modified my HDD icons. 

If so, remember that that that bar is only visible in certain views, like View>Tiles

Comment: Yeah i mean exactly that one and I know that they are only visible in certain views but at this place they are gone ^^ If I revert back then it comes back no Problem but when I take my own dll file then it is gone. I have exact the same Icon resolutions like the default Icon so that is not the Problem

Comment: did you try deleting the icon cache file (see my comment above)?

Comment: Yeah I have a Batch file for that ^^ and i cleaned already up my disk and I restarted the PC nothing helps

Comment: For me, the bars only show up in Tiles and Content view https://i.imgur.com/VqfxJFP.png Your example (https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9Hkq.png ) doesn't appear to be in any of those views as the icons are too large, so I don't think the bars are supposed to be there. Do they not appear when you click on "Tiles" or "Content"?

Comment: no they do not appear in any size option

Comment: Hm I switched User on the Admin account they are there but only on my current user they are gone

Comment: Ok nop now it worked after the switch it did take over https://imgur.com/g8owb3W                        Thank you for your patience and helping through :)